# Functional testing with Python WebTest

Tags: python, pyramid, webtest

I am totally new to functional testing with using Python WebTest, please bear with me

I was looking at https://webtest.readthedocs.org/en/latest/webtest.html, so I tried out the code as suggested to make a request:

```
    app.get('/path', [params], [headers], [extra_environ], ...)
```

Ok, looks simple enough to me. I create a file called test_demo.py in myapp folder:

```
    from webtest import TestApp

    class MyTests():
        def test_admin_login(self):
           resp = self.TestApp.get('/admin')
           print (resp.request)
```

Now this is where I am stuck with, how should I run this test_demo.py?
I've tried typing in bash

```
    $ bin/python MyCart/mycart/test_demo.py test_admin_login
```

But it isn't showing any result.

I bet I got something all wrong, but the docs isn't helping much or I'm just plain slow.

Answer (score 6):

Whoops, you're missing a few steps.

Your program doesn't do anything because you didn't tell it to do anything, you just defined a class. So let's tell it to do something. We'll use the [unittest](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/unittest.html) package to make things a bit more automated.

```
import unittest
from webtest import TestApp

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_admin_login(self):
       resp = self.TestApp.get('/admin')
       print (resp.request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Run that, and we see:

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_admin_login (__main__.MyTests)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_foo.py", line 6, in test_admin_login
    resp = self.TestApp.get('/admin')
AttributeError: 'MyTests' object has no attribute 'TestApp'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Ok, so we need an app to test. Where to get one? You would typically want the WSGI app that you are creating in your `main` via `config.make_wsgi_app()`. The easiest way is to load it up, just like `pserve development.ini` does when you run your app. We can do this via `pyramid.paster.get_app()`.

```
import unittest
from pyramid.paster import get_app
from webtest import TestApp

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_admin_login(self):
        app = get_app('testing.ini')
        test_app = TestApp(app)
        resp = test_app.get('/admin')
        self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Now all that's needed is an INI file similar to your `development.ini`, but for testing purposes. You can just copy `development.ini` until you need to set any settings just for testing.

Hopefully that gives you a starting point to learn more about the `unittest` package.

Comment: There's a new error( ImportError: No module named pyramid.paster ) when I tried  to run $ python -m unittest -v test_demo. I'm using python 3.2

Comment: Use the python from the virtualenv in which you installed pyramid.

Comment: I'm getting an ImportError: Import by filename is not supported. I've use this command MBP:env $ bin/python -m unittest -v MyCart/mycart/test_demo

Comment: You'll have to create separate questions for this stuff since error messages are basically worthless without seeing the full traceback. Since the script is running `unittest.main()` you shouldn't need to use the `-m unittest` in your CLI. Just `env/bin/python MyCart/mycart/test_demo.py`.